# ProgressBar not displaying in FrameLayout WebView

Tags: android, webview

i want to display a progressBar on my WebView while the client is waiting for the webserver doing stuff. The progressBar doesn't display (but it is not null, i checked that already...) Here my xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

and here a snippet of my MainActivity.java:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
        ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
        ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
});
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can use whatever layout you want (relative/linear/constraint or even framelayout) you just need to add layout_gravity.

See the code below:

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
    >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

It does not matter where you put the progressbar before or after the webview component in the xml file. I usually do the loading by hiding/showing the correct component everytime.

See the code below:

```
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
        ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        myWebView.setVisibility(View.Gone);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
        ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        myWebView.setVisibility(View.Visible);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `contraintLayout`.
the way you used this `frameLayout` the `progressBar` is not shown at the center of the screen at all; because layout_centerHorizontal seems to be an invalid argument. if you want to put it in the center you should use `android:layout_gravity="center"`. this will fix your problem.

But as I said, I suggest using `constraintLayout` in a manner like this (note that if you are using androidx you should use androidx tag for ConstraintLayout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Relative layout inside frame layout and put progressBar on the center of  webview. frame Layout inside progress Bar is not shown at the screen at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code insted of your xml code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"   />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</FrameLayout>
```